# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str in Python

Tags: python, json

I have been having this problem for the last 2 days and i can't fix it.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64
name = "koalaaaa"
url = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + name
rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
newrawdata = rawdata.read()
jsondata = json.loads(newrawdata.decode('utf-8'))
results = jsondata['id']
url_uuid = "https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" + results + "/names"
rawdata_uuid = urllib.request.urlopen(url_uuid)
newrawdata_uuid = rawdata_uuid.read()
jsondata_uuid = json.loads(newrawdata_uuid.decode('utf-8'))
results = jsondata_uuid['name']
print (results)
```

and i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/unmigrated.py", line 14, in <module>
results = jsondata_uuid['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: The first step would be to examine `jsondata_uuid`.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsondata_uuid` is a list you cannot use a key to fetch items from it instead you can use numbers.

if it contains a dictionary as the first item you can fetch a value from the dictionary using this for example :

```
results = jsondata_uuid[0]['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

`jsondata_uuid` is a list of dicts, each of which contains a `name`. To print them all out you can do `print([data['name'] for data in jsondata_uuid])`.

Tip: Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `jsondata_uuid` contains a list of dictionaries with something like this:

```
[{'name': 'Deamti'}, {'changedToAt': 1423576506000, 'name': 'ChocolateBanana'}, {'changedToAt': 1426793965000, 'name': 'IMBHARLOW'}, {'changedToAt': 1430137396000, 'name': 'SuckUp'}, {'changedToAt': 1437970183000, 'name': 'lllllll'}, {'changedToAt': 1440592843000, 'name': 'Koalaaaa'}]
```

Which 'name' key you want?

Change the line `results = jsondata_uuid['name']` for `results = jsondata_uuid` and you will see the results. Then, you can think of a way of sorting the names out.

Comment: I basically want to sort out all of the names like "Deamti" and "ChocolateBanana"

Comment: Change the line `results = jsondata_uuid['name']` for `results = jsondata_uuid` and you will see the results. Then, you can think of a way of sorting the names out.

Comment: @RonaldKaiser if this is the actual answer to the question it shouldn't be hidden in a comment - add it to your answer using the `edit` option.